# How to list files and substitute pattern in makefile

Tags: sed, makefile

I have scripts like this

```
#!/bin/sh
SHELL_CMD=busybox
```

and try to substitute some pattern to bash shell using makefile,

```
#!/bin/bash
#SHELL_CMD=busybox
```

Followings are the procedures in Makefile

```
release:
    @rm -rf my_temp/
    @mkdir my_temp/
    @cp dir1/burn_*.sh dir1/dump_*.sh my_temp/
    @cd my_temp/; \
        for f in $(shell ls); do \
            sed 's:#!/bin/sh\nSHELL_CMD=busybox:#!/bin/bash\n#SHELL_CMD=busybox:1' $${f} > temp; mv temp $${f}; \
        done; \
        cd ..;
    @cd my_temp/; tar -jcv -f bash.tar.bz2 *.sh; cd ..;
```

My questions are:

1 in the for loop, it didn't get the correct script names in for loop.
How to patch it ?

2. Any better patterns in this sed substitution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are much better off doing the substitution without trying to match the newline in the source string. Unless you are ready to do some complex sed-fu ([How can I replace a newline (\n) using sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1251999/5291015)) you can just apply the substitution on each of the line with a

You can do this to apply the action on both 1st and 2nd lines. Also the `$(shell ls)` part is not needed. You can just run a shell glob expression to get you the files ending with `.sh`

```
@for f in *.sh; do \
    sed -i -e '1 s:#!/bin/sh:#!/bin/bash:1' -e '2 s:^:#:1' $${f} ;\
done
```

If you don't want the `-i` in-place substitution, use the `tmp` file approach as you had originally shown.